# Backstack like instagram with viewpager and BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, instagram, bottomnavigationview, back-stack, android-viewpager2

I have created an android app ([Sample APK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpnujd4utxlnwju/app-debug.apk?dl=0) & [Github Repo](https://github.com/Srt9930/BackStackProblemSample)) where I implement a `BottomNavigationBar` with `ViewPager`. Navigation is ok but I don't know how to handle the back stack in a viewpager like Instagram.

I tried the below code but this way I have to create an unnecessary fragment where I never navigate.

```
 view_pager_main_activity?.currentItem = view_pager_main_activity.currentItem - 1
```

suppose I just launch the app to the 1st page and then navigate to the 3rd page by BottomNavBar but now if I click the back button, I go back to the 1st page through the 2nd page. So this way I create the unwanted 2nd page.

Here is the whole back stack process onBackPressed()

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

       if (view_pager_main_activity?.currentItem == 0) {
            if (view_pager_main_fragment?.currentItem == 0) {
                val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.listRecyclerView)
                val appbarHome = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.appbar_home)
                val layoutManager = recyclerView?.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
                when {
                    layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0 -> {
                        super.onBackPressed()
                    }
                    supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount != 0 -> {
                        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0)
                        appbarHome.setExpanded(true)
                    }
                }
            } else if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount != 0) {
                super.onBackPressed()
            } else {
                view_pager_main_fragment?.setCurrentItem(
                        view_pager_main_fragment.currentItem - 1,
                        false
                )
            }
        } else if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount != 0) {
            super.onBackPressed()
        } else {
            view_pager_main_activity?.currentItem = view_pager_main_activity.currentItem - 1
        }
    }
```

I want back stack navigation as same as Instagram so I tried [this](https://github.com/f22labs/InstaLikeFragmentTransaction) way but has deprecated.
I don't know how can I achieve that.

Comment: What you should be using is a navigation graph with bottom navigation, you'll get the desired flow. check out the doc here -> https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started